# Independently sized buckets for multi-faceted histogram plot

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

in plotly express:

I want to plot the histograms of multiple columns, that are on **different scales**.

I need the buckets of each subolot to be indepent of the others.

here is the code:

```py
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
df['total_bill_times_100'] = df['total_bill']*100
df_plot = df.melt(value_vars = ['total_bill','total_bill_times_100' ])
fig = px.histogram(df_plot, x="value", facet_col = 'variable', template='simple_white')
fig.update_yaxes(matches=None)
fig.update_xaxes(matches=None)
fig.show()
```

Current output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `px.histogram()` with `facet_col`, the facetted subplots will share the same [`bingroup`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/histogram/#histogram-bingroup)

> `bingroup`: Set a group of histogram traces which will have compatible bin
> settings [...]

... which will make them have the same bin size, that is, `200`.

You can set the bingroup to `None` so that the bin size in each histogram is computed individually :

```
fig = px.histogram(df_plot, x="value", facet_col = 'variable', template='simple_white')
fig.update_yaxes(matches=None)
fig.update_xaxes(matches=None)

fig.update_traces(bingroup=None)

fig.show()
```

The bin size of 'total_bill' and 'total_bill_times_100' is now `2` and `200` respectively so the distribution is exactly the same :

[image: screenshot]

If fine tuning is needed, use `plotly.graph_objects` instead of `plotly.express`, see [Custom binning](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/#custom-binning).

Comment: ahh that was the trick. thank you!